# Seeking affine reparameterization of a curve

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, relativity

A ray of light propagates along the straight line

$$x(p) = \frac{p}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$y(p) = \frac{p}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$z(p) = \frac{p}{\sqrt{3}},$$

where $p$ is a parameter.

Reparameterize this curve with a new parameter $\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is an affine parameter. The metric is flat, $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2-c^2dt^2$

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.